# Testing django view with form that contains ModelChoiceField

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-forms

Here is the form that am using to send data to the view :

```py
class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'placeholder': _('User Name')
    }))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'placeholder': _('Password')

    }))
    roles = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Role.objects.exclude(role_name="Admin"), widget=forms.Select(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
    }))
```

And Here is the view am testing with the form in it :

```py
def register(request):
    user = request.user
    current_user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=user.username)
    if current_user.role.role_name == "Admin":
        register_form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if request.method == "POST":
            if register_form.is_valid():
                username = register_form.cleaned_data['username']
                password = register_form.cleaned_data['password']
                role = register_form.cleaned_data['roles']
                if CustomUser.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                    messages.error(request, _('Username already exists.'))
                else:
                    new_user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password, role=role)
                    messages.success(request, _('User created Successfully'))
                    return redirect("user_details", pk=new_user.pk)
        else:
            register_form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        context = {
            'register_form': register_form,
        }
        return render(request, 'register.html', context)
    else:
        messages.error(request, _('You are not allowed to view this page.'))
        return redirect('index')
```

Here is how I try to test it by sending post request (`reverse`) with data:

```py
    def test_post_request_correct_date(self):
        call_command("start_app")
        self.client.login(username='user', password='pass')
        waiter_role = Role.objects.get(role_name="Waiter")
        url = reverse('register')
        data = {
            'username': 'new_user',
            'password': 'just good password',
            'roles': waiter_role.pk
        }
        response = self.client.post(url, data, follow=True)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        new_user = CustomUser.objects.get(username="new_user")
        self.assertRedirects(response, reverse('user_details', args={"pk": new_user.pk}))
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'user_profile.html')
```

please note that `call_command("start_app")` is custom command that creates the roles i choose from it.

I get this error :

```
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
AssertionError: 200 != 302
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert on this but I believe if you set `follow=true` in your post the `status_code` in the response is set to the `status_code` of the last element of the `redirect_chain` - which is 200.

This is basically what assertRedirects checks, so I think the "manual" check of the status_code here

```
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
```

is unnecessary and can be removed.